# How to add Rounded corners with HTML

Tags: html, css, image, border

I want to round the corners of this image. Here is what I have in my body.....

```
<body>
   <h1 style="float:left; width:37%;"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">MrEpicGaming4U</font></h1>
   <div style="float:left; class="websiteart"><img src="website_art.png" height= "100" width= "300"/></div>
   <h1 style="float:right;"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">The Art of Gaming</font></h1>
</body>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `<font>` tags aren't supported anymore, please replace.

Comment: You can use the checkmark to accept an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use css [border-radius](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/border-radius)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EExCF/)

```
.websiteart img{
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the prefix versions, just `border-radius` is fine.

Comment: You still have to add the prefixed versions if you want it to work with older browser versions. http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/border-radius#Compatibility

Comment: True, but the `-moz-` one was dropped in FF v13. We're now on FF v21. The `-webkit-` one was dropped way before even that...

Comment: @user2426533 check out the jsFiddle

Comment: @Zenith People still using older versions, if you're using a old device like the iPhone 3G not to mention Android devices, you're stuck with that old software.

Comment: @Vitim.us Browsers aren't devices though, and Chrome/Firefox automatically updates versions without even telling you, whenever there's a new version available...

Comment: @Zenith Browsers have minimum requirements to install, if you have a old device, you can't get the lastest version of the OS. Like I said, if you have a 1st gen iPod Touch you can install iOS up to 3.0 and it run Webkit 3.0, and you can't install the lastest Chrome which require iOS 5.0 or later

Comment: @Vitim.us Why are you talking about 1st generation iPod touches? This discussion is about the browser itself. Google dropped support for the -webkit- border radius over 15 versions of Chrome ago. Most developers find it's use unnecessary, that is all I'm saying. No need for the extended discussion about it. Continue as you were if you insist.

Comment: @Zenith Ok, this is up to the developer decision, if the experience of a few visitors doesn't matter just to drop the 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `border-radius` with the "em" notation, which I like most because I find it easier. Example:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
-webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
-khtml-border-radius: 0.5em;
border-radius: 0.5em;
```

In this case, you will obtain a perfectly rounded corners.